# How to dynamically embed a pdf(locally stored in browser) in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, web, embed

I tried to use embed and iframe tags which work for the first page.

```
<iframe src="~/Documents/Upload/myPDF.pdf" id="pdfDisplay">
```

But when I try to change the src in javascript, I get the same page displayed over again.

```
document.getElementById('pdfDisplay').setAttribute("src", "~/Documents/TextDetection/Upload/" + files[currentIndex]);
```

Where files[currentIndex] is the dynamically generated filename that exists in the local storage.

I don't know what I am doing wrong because its not working.

Comment: sure you don't have a closure problem? currentindex is set to the last value in your loop? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: I printed the file names to check, and they do change. So don't think its a closure problem.